# Unable to create android project with phone gap

Tags: cordova

I am trying to create an Android project with phone gap. I am using the create command in the bin directory. In the image you can find my input and the error I get which is:

```
ANDROID_BIN="${ANDROID_BIN:=$( which android )}"
```

exited with 1

I already downloaded the Android sdk, I plugged it on Eclipse, but I don't know how to link the Android SDK to the Phone gap "create" command. I think this is the source of the error from what I understood reading on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup your PATH variable correctly so that, cordova knows which sdk to pickup

You can find the documentation here: 
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html